# Calculate a middle color from two colors (from a gradient)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, math, colors

I my WPF application, I have two color object.
I would like to calculate the "middle" color from my two colors.

My two color are from a gradient and I would like to find the middle color.

Can anyone help me calculate this ?

Comment: Do you have the Hex or RGB color values for your Gradient Start & Stop?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have the RGB values for the colours, you can do this by linearly interpolating them. If the original colours are `(R1, G1, B1)` and `(R2, G2, B2)` the colour in between them can be found by averaging: `((R1 + R2) / 2, (G1 + G2) / 2, (B1 + B2) / 2)`.

(Assuming you're only looking for the colour in the middle - if you're looking to calculate the whole gradient, use [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) on each component.)

Comment: Thanks ! How doing this ? Like this ?   Color myColorMiddle = new Color();
            myColorMiddle.R=((byte)(Color1.R+Color2.R) / (byte)2)